# Would Bronze and/or Iron weapons and armor have different stats than "typical" ones in games?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e

I thought about asking this in Worldbuilding, but since this specifically includes stats for said items, I figured I'd ask here. I want to create a Mid-Late Ancient Era (Classical Greco-Roman) type world and I was wondering if there's any difference in the stats of, say, a strong bronze or an iron sword compared to a typical 'shortsword' found in any run-of-the-mill inventory?

Answer (score 4):

Bronze weapons in Pathfinder are distinguished by being made from [the material bronze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Bronze), which imparts them the "fragile" quality. For plain iron weapons, there's no real difference (and similarly, you'd use bronze for copper etc.). There are also [some specifically bronze age weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/bronze-age-weapons) listed.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, that actually helps a lot, I never even know Pathfinder came up with a list. I suppose I just have to retroactively go back to adjust the current weapons of this typical Medieval setting. I like Medieval Era, but it's also cliched and I want something different.

Answer (score 1):

**Both systems have rules for bronze but not for iron.**

Pathfinder has [rules specifically for bronze weapons & armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Bronze) (basically identical to steel except it has the *fragile* quality).

From the Arms & Equipment Guide (D&D 3.0) p12:

> Weapons of bronze, while clearly inferior to steel items, are not nearly as bad as stone or bone weapons. Their attack and damage penalty is only -1... Their hardness is 9.

Neither system appears to have rules for non-steel iron equipment. The DM could treat it as bronze or as steel, or come up with their own stats for it.

Comment: That's what it's looking like, that'll have to be a specific project for my worldbuilding  it seems. But thank you, I never even realized Pathfinder had special rules for special materials until now.